# Campos de formulário não clicável em site quando abertos em desktop?

Tags: html, formulário

http://pousadamonteiro.com.br/Contato.html

Possuo um modelo de formulário de contato que usa JS para validar e PHP para enviar os dados, porém nesse site que o link está acima, o formulário não está clicável quando aberto no desktop (em mobile ele funciona normalmente). Já rodei todo html e não encontrei o que poderia ser. Alguem poderia me ajudar indicando onde seria a fonte do problema?

Agradeço desde já

Answer (score 1):

Tira o `position: relative` da tag `<p>` no seu CSS que resolve o problema. Ficando assim:

```
p{
    line-height:1.8em;
    font-family: 'Hind', sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Problema está que a div com a classe "**well**" está aparecendo acima da div que contém o botão. É fácil verifica isso utilizando o comando F12 no seu navegador para verificar o posicionamento dos elementos na pagina.

**Segue print:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]